# Type Error Occured in python executed in visual studio

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am running the below code to calculate current age in python using visual studio.

but i am getting the below piece of error: 
Error:

```
Type Error Occured
Unsupported operand Type for built_in_function or method
```

code:

```
import datetime

def my_current_age():
    user_input = input("enter year")
    date_of_birth = (datetime.date(1990 , 10 , 28))
    today_date=(datetime.date.today)
    current_age = (today_date - date_of_birth)
    print("you lived for {}" .format(current_age))


print(my_current_age())
```

any suggestion python developer please

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to call `datetime.date.today`.

Comment: And remove the space between `"you lived for {}"` and `.format(...)`.

Comment: @Rawing: Thanks Rawing. new to python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a method of `datetime` to `today_date` with:

```
today_date=(datetime.date.today)
```

i.e, you are *calling* the function. Call it, instead:

```
today_date=(datetime.date.today())
```

in order for it to work.

Apart from that, take note that the parenthesis around your expressions are redundant, that is:

```
today_date=(datetime.date.today())
```

is directly equivalent to:

```
today_date = datetime.date.today()
```